# Is it possible to standardize types in an interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

```
export interface BookProps {
  link: string;
  title: string;
  image: string;
  author: string;
  discount: string;
  publisher: string;
  description: string;
}
```

Is there a way to express that all elements in the interface have a string type in a concise manner?

Comment: Do you need to keep that list of known keys? Or just “any property that happens to exist will have a `string` value”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use index properties to achieve a general interface definition.

```
interface Book {
    [prop: string]: string;
}

const nineteenEightyFour: Book = {
    link: "https://...",
    title: "nineteenEightyFour",
    .... 
}
```

Ts should be happy enough with this.